# Correctly implementing PagerAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have problems with implementation of my custom PagerAdapter and using it with a ViewPager.
This sample PagerAdapter has 10 items, every item is a button with it's index as text.
When I run my program, I see a button with text '1' insted of '0'. And when I swipe to other items I get only blank views. When I swipe backwards sometimes I see a button with some number, but it disappears (maybe it is destroying and I remove it from the container), and sometimes I see a button with a number, but the number changes after the swipe (I think I create a new Button and I add it to the container, and for some reasons the viewpager shows this new button).

How can I fix this implementation? I haven't seen difference in examples.

My PagerAdapter implementation:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o.getClass()==view.getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Button button = new Button(container.getContext());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(-1,-1);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        container.addView(button);
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((Button)object);
    }
}
```

And my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `o.getClass()==view.getClass()` with `o==view` in the `isViewFromObject()` method.

Answer (score 16):

Here is complete code:

xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.androidviewpagerapp.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyPagerAdapter class:

```
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o==view;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Button button = new Button(container.getContext());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setText(String.valueOf(position));

        final int page = position;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(container.getContext(), "You clicked: " + page + ". page.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        container.addView(button);
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((Button)object);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

You will see that Buttons are full screen. To avoid that you need to create some layout (like LinearLayout) and add button to that layout.

Example:

```
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o==view;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Button button = new Button(container.getContext());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setText(String.valueOf(position));

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(container.getContext());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        //add buton to layout
        layout.addView(button);

        final int page = position;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(container.getContext(), "You clicked: " + page + ". page.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //to container add layout instead of button
        container.addView(layout);
        //return layout instead of button
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        //cast to LinearLayout
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the view pager inside of the MainActivity xml file?

Comment: Please , the height of the viewPager is not equal to the height of the items .. the items are shown cut and the height is not correct , how can I fix this , here is my question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66862287/11567530

Answer (score 6):

> if you want to inflate views in pager you must have to implement two methods.
>   **instantiateItem and destroyItem**

```
public class DialogPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    //view inflating..
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_dialog_signin_viewpagers,
                collection, false);

        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tvLabel.setText("Log In");
                tvLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 1:
                tvLabel.setText("Sign Up");
                tvLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                tvLabel.setText("Send Reset Link");
                tvLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //onOptionClickForgot.OnOptionClick();
                    }
                });
                break;
        }

        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Simply call it like

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new DialogPagerAdapter);
```

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_button_height"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_2"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_2"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/dialog_button_height">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I thought you must always override these [four methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager/widget/PagerAdapter) at minimum?

Answer (score 0):

Here i post `ViewPagerAdapter` that attached between `TabLayout` to `ViewPager`

```java
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Fragment> fragment = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(String title, Fragment fragment) {
        this.titleList.add(title);
        this.fragment.add(fragment);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragment.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titleList.size();
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

How to use `ViewPagerAdapter`.

```java
 ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 adapter.addFragment("TAB 1", new YOUR_FRAGMENT1());
 adapter.addFragment("TAB 2", new YOUR_FRAGMENT2());
 // Keep adding fragments.
 viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```