# How to solve issue with PagerAdapter on Kotlin: "Required method instantiateItem was not overridden"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-pageradapter, kotlin-android-extensions

So my project is calling Kotlin file to Java :

This is the error message (Run Time Error) I got: 
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Required method instantiateItem was not overridden`

this is my **app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
....
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
....
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
}
```

my **project gradle** looks:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
    repositories {
...

}
dependencies {
....
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
```

and last, this is my **kotlin** code,

```
class SwipeAdapter : PagerAdapter {
....
...
    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup?, position: Int):Any {
      .....
     ....
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position)
    }

    .....
}
```

(I tried to change it to java.lang.Object but of course got a compilation error,
it must be type of Any for Kotlin)

called on **java** file:

```
PagerAdapter sa= new SwipeAdapter(someArgs);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the exception because you're still delegating the work to the `super` call, which then calls into this implementation:

```
@Deprecated
@NonNull
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull View container, int position) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Required method instantiateItem was not overridden");
}
```

Instead of calling the `super` method, you should return an object you create that represents the page at the given position. This is usually the `View` itself, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356506/correctly-implementing-pageradapter-in-android) or [this tutorial](https://inducesmile.com/android/understanding-android-viewpager-and-custom-pageradapter/) for `PagerAdapter` examples.