# Making the height of the ViewPager equal to the highest item in the PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, textview, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` and use it to swipe between views not Fragments .
And when I give the `View Pager` wrap_content height , it doesn't show anything . So I had to give it a fixed height . But I had another problem , when the item's height is larger than the fixed one , the view doesn't be shown correctly (And I use `TextView` as the View) . So what should I do to make the height of the `ViewPager` is equal to the highest one .

I use `PagerAdapter` like the code below .

```
public class IndicatorViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public int[] images = {R.drawable.userprofile,R.drawable.userprofile,R.drawable.userprofile,R.drawable.userprofile,R.drawable.userprofile};
    public int[] texts = {R.string.first_text,R.string.second_text,R.string.third_text,R.string.fourth_text,R.string.fifth_text};
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Typeface typeface;
    String lang;
    public IndicatorViewPagerAdapter(Context context,String lang) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lang=lang;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return texts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_item_layout,null);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        String text = context.getResources().getString(texts[position]);
        Log.e("text"," "+text);
        textView.setText(text);
        //ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
        if(lang.equals("en")) {
            typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.knowledge_regular);
        }
        else {
            typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.thesans_plain);
        }
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
        container.addView(view);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        viewPager.removeView(view);
    }


}
```

and Here I use the `ViewPager` in `XML`

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#85d7d5d6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/leftArrowTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/arrow_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp" />

                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rightArrowTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/arrow_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any one tell me if my question is not clear

Comment: Try providing a parent view for the inflation like this: `View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_item_layout, container);`

Comment: @Cheticamp I already added this line in the code , please see it again

Comment: I don't see that line. I see something a line that has `null` as the second argument but not what I suggest with `container` as the second argument.

Comment: @Cheticamp when I add the container I get this error 
lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Setting `false` as the third parameter to the `inflate()` will probably get rid of that problem but,. pon reflection, I don't think this is where you problem is.

Comment: Why not using a ScrollView as root element of the ViewPager page view

Comment: @Zain I use NestedScrollView 



 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330639/dynamic-height-viewpager/32410274#32410274) will certainly help you. I've added this code a while back and it worked like a charm. 1 thing to note though, if you have  a TabLayout, you need to ADD it's height to the total, otherwise it'll be that much shorther than it needs to be.

Comment: @Vucko Thanks but it's not helping

Comment: If you could be slightly more elaborate, it'd help you get this sorted

Comment: @Vucko what exactly you need of the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you posted your `IndicatorViewPagerAdapter` code.

Your adapter code is used to **populate** data, it has nothing to do with the size of the view, which is the `ViewPager`.

To me it probably makes more sense to try and customize the viewpager and apply manual resize logic. So I looked for this on stackoverflow, as found a popular stackoverflow post where you even commented on, but it seems you were also confused on how to actually implement it. To be clear, I haven't tested this at all but it seems you were confused by the difference between **adapters** and **views**.

```
public class WrapContentHeightViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public WrapContentHeightViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WrapContentHeightViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int height = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if(h > height) height = h;
        }

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Then change your XML to

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/leftArrowTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/arrow_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp" />

            <my.package.name.WrapContentHeightViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rightArrowTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/arrow_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I use this function in the class https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784791/11567530

it make the height of the viewPager equal to the highest item , bit I found a problem , if one of the item in the ViewPager is an image , the viewPager's heigh become big because of the image , so how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it's working with a slight change. You just need to check your ViewPager item's design. ViewPager displays even with wrap_content height. Look at the below code:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.feeds_item_layout,container, false);
    ...
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: when I tried the line of the layoutInflater , it's not working . The height of the ViewPager is like 10dp .. all views in it are cut

Comment: Did you check? You set the static height to LinearLayout, parent of ViewPager - @dimen/_150sdp

Comment: how I can check my ViewPager's design ?